# “if parties create a breach of contract then this agreement is null and void and the division of proceeds shall be decided by court of law.” Meaning?

Tags: contract-law, family-law

I am supposed to get 100% of the net proceeds for sale of a home as stated in an agreement drawn up by attorneys. However at the end of the agreement it says  “If the actions of the parties create a breach of contract for the sale of the home then this Agreement shall be null and void and the division of the proceeds shall be decided by a Court of Law.” Is this saying if the other 2 parties do not give me the proceeds then what’s in this agreement doesn’t mean anything?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the lawyer who drew it up?

Answer (score 1):

What the clause says is, literally, that "If the actions of the parties create a breach of contract for the sale of the home then this Agreement shall be null and void and the division of the proceeds shall be decided by a Court of Law". It is impossible to determine what the big-picture meaning of the agreement is w.r.t. a specific case. You can surmise from the words that somebody will have to sue somebody else and the courts will sort it out, but nothing in that wording says anything about you getting any money, or what would constitute a breach of contract. This is why you have to ask a lawyer who reads the actual agreement and asks you pertinent questions (also why we don't give specific legal advice).